# Website layout distorted on Uc mini

Tags: html, css, web, uc-browser

We're trying to test our [website](http://www.smartprix.com) for compatibility on different browsers.

So, we are facing problems while testing with `UC mini` browser. The website looks fine when the speed mode is off. But with speed mode on, the website is really distorted. The alignment of different elements is not correct and are distorted (you can check screenshots for more details).

We've checked that the `html` code is same for both speed mode on and off.

So, how can we fix this issue?

Is there a way to correct this from our end?

**Speed mode off**

[image: Speed mode off]

**Speed mode on**

[image: Speed mode on]

Comment: Would it be possible to create a snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: the website is live, you can see the screenshots or can check yourself on the UC mini.

Comment: A stacksnippet right here in the question would be way better. Firstly, not everybody is fond of clicking random links. Secondly, if it's a proper snippet, we can copy it and edit it to see if we can find out what the problem is; obviously we can't edit your website! And thirdly, and most importantly, what we need is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that doesn't contain anything not relevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: yeah, i would love to post a snippet but i'm not sure what snippet to post here to demonstrate the above issue, it would be great if you could tell me that

Comment: If you look at the output from the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartprix.com%2F), it returns 75 issues, many of which might be responsible for the issues (structural errors such as hr in ul and such).

Comment: yeah checked that, will fix those errors. btw can you tell what does the browser do in the speed mode? cuz it works fine normally and also on other browsers(chrome, firefox..)

Comment: @Ashish Ranjan. Same problem with my website. If You got solution then please share. My website working fine with UC Browser but not in UC MINI with Speed mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908037/website-is-not-working-in-mobileuc-browser-and-opera-mini

Comment: Same issue with my website as well. Please post the fix, if you already found any.